# swaping value of NSArray objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

This is an array. How can I swap the values as per my requirement. 
As you can see the in below example first value of the array and the third value will be swap. then the 4th value to 6th value and so on..

```
" 198.16666666418314, 199.75",  <- swap this
"203.5, 198.5",
"200, 196.5",                   <- to this
" 199.83333332836628, 217",     <- swap this
"196.33333332836628, 203",
"196.16666665673256, 211.5",    <- to this
" 218.5, 227.5",                <- swap this
"203.5, 222.5",
"211, 225"                      <- to this
```

I am new in ios guys no idea to solve this.

Basically I have this output value

```
2015-08-07 08:45:14.505 ifonter[43240:1784538] VALUE <UIBezierPath: 0x7fd5c8483de0; <MoveTo {232.5, 255.5}>,
<CurveTo {233.58333337306976, 277.58333325386047} {232.5, 263.5} {232.5, 271.5}>,
<CurveTo {239.33333337306976, 290.91666650772095} {234.66666674613953, 283.66666650772095} {236.83333349227905, 287.83333301544189}>,
<CurveTo {247.5, 298} {241.83333325386047, 294} {244.66666650772095, 296}>
```

And I'm trying to clean up (see code below)

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\<UIBezierPath:(.*?)\\;" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: self.fl.strPaths options:0 range: NSMakeRange(0, [self.fl.strPaths length]) withTemplate:@""];

NSString *strMovTo = [modifiedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<MoveTo {" withString:@"M"];
strMovTo = [strMovTo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}>," withString:@"-"];

strMovTo = [strMovTo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<CurveTo {" withString:@""];
strMovTo = [strMovTo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"} {" withString:@"-"];
strMovTo = [strMovTo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}>" withString:@""];
strMovTo = [strMovTo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];


NSArray *elements = [strMovTo componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

Comment: Where's your code that you've tried?

Comment: please look the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your array name is `myArray`

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@" 198.16666666418314, 199.75",@"203.5, 198.5", and so on... ];


NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myArray];

for(int i=0;i<[newArray count];i=i+3)
{
  [newArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:i+2];
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop?

Comment: one last question to @Lalit Kumar
how to bring it back to String with this format

  "C 233.58333337306976, 277.58333325386047 232.5, 263.5 232.5, 271.5 
  C 239.33333337306976, 290.91666650772095 234.66666674613953,   283.66666650772095 236.83333349227905, 287.83333301544189 
  C 247.5, 298 241.83333325386047, 294 244.66666650772095, 296"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's a `NSMutableArray`.

Then you can use [exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BCIJIGDB) to swap the values.

Comment: how to bring it back to String with this format "C 233.58333337306976, 277.58333325386047 232.5, 263.5 232.5, 271.5 C 239.33333337306976, 290.91666650772095 234.66666674613953, 283.66666650772095 236.83333349227905, 287.83333301544189 C 247.5, 298 241.83333325386047, 294 244.66666650772095, 296"